# Component condition isn't working without UI

Tags: wix

I have trouble with component in wix when I make update without ui.

```
<Component Id="PrinterConfEnable" Guid="911F0032-A217-4B1F-B973-29DB6DC06952">

    <util:XmlFile Id="PrinterEnabled" Action="setValue" Permanent="yes" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]\config.xml" ElementPath="/printer/enabled" Value="true" />

    <Condition>
        <![CDATA[ USE_PRINTER_VAL = "1" and USE_PRINTER_0_VAL = "1" ]]>
    </Condition>

</Component>

<Component Id="PrinterConfDisable" Guid="56AD5D4B-3700-44E1-9A0F-03E3A2A5D88F">

    <util:XmlFile Id="PrinterDisabled" Action="setValue" Permanent="yes" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]\config.xml" ElementPath="/printer/enabled" Value="false" />

    <Condition>
        <![CDATA[ USE_PRINTER_VAL <> "1" or USE_PRINTER_0_VAL <> "1" ]]>
    </Condition>

</Component>
```

During updating properties USE_PRINTER_VAL and USE_PRINTER_0_VAL are equal 1 but in config.xml it has been written

```
<printer> 
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</printer>
```

However when I update with UI it works properly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these values are set in the UI, and "update without UI" means a feature change or patch (or something like that) then:

You are probably assuming that once property values are set in the UI they are saved somewhere for later use. They are not saved unless you save them, so they revert to the default values. WiX has a "remember property" pattern you can use to save the values so that the values originally entered will be saved and restored on other servicing activities like patches, updates etc.

http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/

Even if they are being set somewhere, they need be marked as secure to ensure that they pass correctly into the execute sequence.

Comment: Before InstallInitialize I take values from old config.xml and set them in  USE_PRINTER_VAL and USE_PRINTER_0_VAL 
To make sure these properties are equal 1 I add the folowing
`<util:XmlFile Id="PrinterDisabled" Action="setValue" Permanent="yes" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]\config.xml" ElementPath="/printer/test" Value="[USE_PRINTER_VAL] [USE_PRINTER_0_VAL]" />`

and I get folowing 
  <br/>  
`<printer> 
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <test>1 1</test>
    </printer>`

Comment: "Before InstallInitilize" presumably means a custom action, but there's no evidence that the this CA is being called or that it's setting values, and apparently it isn't! . You should perform the update producing a verbose log and see what's being called, and when, and whjere the valus are set.